# Is there a nice way to access parent methods in Flask routes?

Tags: python, flask

Say I have an app created like this:

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 4
        self.app = create_app()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    parent = Parent()
    parent.app.run(debug=True)
```

With registered blueprints in some __init __.py file from a module containing the static, templates folders etc:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Heya!'

    from .views import views

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')

    return app
```

And with a views.py file containing this:

```
views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Is there a nice way to to access methods or properties from the parent class inside the route?
Of course this doesn't work but for explanation:

```
@views.route('/')
def index():
    value = parent.value
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Or more generally, how can I reach objects outside the app that maybe run in different threads for example? Normally I would pass the parent, but I have no idea how to achieve this here.

Comment: I got it to work using MethodView and passing the parent in the constructor, but I'm still open to suggestions